# Bootstrap Vue n-dropdown throws mismatching child node warning

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap Vue 2 and am using the `<b-dropdown>` component. I need to render a custom component within each dropdown item, on initial page and navigating it looks okay, but a reload of any individual page shows the custom component twice, what am I missing?

> Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes

This is what it looks like, I shouldn't be seeing it twice since I only have it defined once:

[image]

Here's my dropdown component:

```html
<b-dropdown variant="primary" right toggle-class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-md-lg rounded-pill" no-caret>
  <template #button-content>
    Import
  </template>
  <b-dropdown-item :disabled="($auth.user && !$auth.user.is_subscribed)" to="/account/bulk-imports/create/?type=domains">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="heroicon-sm flex-shrink-0 mr-1">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3 16.5v2.25A2.25 2.25 0 005.25 21h13.5A2.25 2.25 0 0021 18.75V16.5m-13.5-9L12 3m0 0l4.5 4.5M12 3v13.5" />
    </svg>
    Import domains <MiniProBadge />
  </b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item :disabled="($auth.user && !$auth.user.is_subscribed)" to="/account/bulk-imports/create/?type=monitors">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="heroicon-sm flex-shrink-0 mr-1">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3 16.5v2.25A2.25 2.25 0 005.25 21h13.5A2.25 2.25 0 0021 18.75V16.5m-13.5-9L12 3m0 0l4.5 4.5M12 3v13.5" />
    </svg>
    Import monitors <MiniProBadge />
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

Although not likely required for this, here's my mini badge component:

```html
<template>
  <b-badge v-if="($auth.user && !$auth.user.is_subscribed)" to="/account/subscriptions/checkout/" v-b-tooltip.hover title="Only available on our Pro plan. Upgrade now." variant="warning" class="small py-0 px-1 ml-1 mr-1" style="font-size: 11px; padding-top: 5px !important; padding-bottom: 5px !important; max-height: 21px !important;">
    PRO
  </b-badge>
</template>
```

The warning:

[image]

### UPDATE 1

Interestingly, if I remove to `to` attribute from my badge, the duplication behaviour disappears. Ideally I'd still like it to be a link. Any suggestions?